# 16.04.02 crashes after backup

Tags: 16.04, backup, ram, crash

I'm experiencing 16.04.02 total crashes during night since 2 days.

i was able to see the error shortly -> vm ran out of memory.
the vm was installed in january with 4GB RAM, after first crash i upgraded to 8GB.
But when i start the VM Backup (veeam) the available memory is going down for 10-15 MB/s till 0 -> then crash

**Edit from comment:**

My partition layout is as shown. [image: PLayout]

Comment: Do you have a swap partition or swapfile? Show me the output of `free -h`.

Comment: What do you do on this VM that even 8GB is not enough for it?

Comment: i have swap
there is only nginx running on this VM. i set i up with 4GB RAM, but after first crash i added 4GB (just to see). during normal operation there are 90% free memory -> just when starting VM backup (Hyper-V) RAM will be used as hell till out of memory

here are my partitions:

Comment: [link](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=b2b9af-1490948088.png)

Comment: It's not surprising (at least to me) that running a backup would utilize a lot of RAM is it's likely caching content like mad. The crashing on the other hand is unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Bug in kernel starts with 4.4.0-67, workaround: remove DVD from the VM.
Works in my case.

Comment: This seems to be an incomplete answer, otherwise potentially a useful answer. Consider to include supporting details and explain how to set up the solution. In particular, quote link to bug report [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1674635) and [another one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1679898). The latter has recent comments (#47 and onwards) that mentioned "removing DVD from VM" works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this issue is a regression from [this previously fixed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1663687) as mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1679898/comments/19) If I'm understanding correctly this is possibly due to changes in HyperV.

The workaround touched on in the partial yet useful [@noirfry answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/903107/225694) is mentioned in the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1679898/comments/47) and confirmed [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1679898/comments/48)